# Magento : Shipping method cheapest rate selected as default on checkout page

Tags: magento

I have multiple shipping methods and each shipping method have different types of rates base on product weight.

How can I display shipping method selected as default which have minimum rates on checkout page?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Javascript (jQuery).

Search for the fields and the price values, find the smallest values and programmatically, check the field that has the lowest value.

Problem Solved!!

## UPDATED (pseudo code)

```
<html>
.......
<div class="ship_methods">
<input name="ship1" class="ship_unit"> 40 </input>
<input name="ship2" class="ship_unit"> 50 </input>
<input name="ship3" class="ship_unit"> 60 </input>
</div>
...
</html>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var smallest = 99999;//set anything larger ;
  var elem;
  $(".ship_unit").each(function() {
  // iterated over all the class elements.
    getVal = $(this).findYourRequiredValueOrAttr();
    if( smallest > getVal){
       smallest = getVal;
       elem= $(this);// get the input object
    }
  });
elem.prop("checked", true);
});
```

It's just a pseudo code but you should get the idea.

Comment: Can you please explain with small example (with just two input) ?